# Integer input to a function that expects const reference

Tags: c++, reference, constants

I dont know if a similar question is asked before, but i couldnt know how to search it, duplicate tag is welcome if you provide me a link :)

so i ask :

```
#include <iostream>

class H
{
   public:
      H(int x = 0)
      {
         std::cout << "constructor";
      }
};

void func1(const H &a1)
{

}

int main()
{
    func1(15);
    return 0;
}
```

Can you explain what is going on here? Why does it accept int value as const reference, calls constructor etc?

Thanks.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`H` has an implicit converting constructor that allows it to be constructed from an int like this:

```
H h = 42;
```

When you pass `15` to `func1`, a temporary `H` object is created by calling `H(15)`. This temporary is used in the function. In C++, it is OK to bind a temporary object to a `const` reference.

If you want to disallow these implicit conversions, make the constructor `explicit`:

```
explicit H(int x = 0) { ... }
```